# Show Additional <div> if Variable Equals This or This

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple forms site where I need to show an additional  only if the department selected is one of three --- Engineering, IT, or Product. The below function works, but I am only able to list one department. It does nothing if I put all three in one set of quotes or in comma-separated individual sets of quotes. Is there a better function to accomplish this?

```
$("#department").change(function() {
    if ($("#department").val() == "IT" || $("#department").val () == "Modify") {
        $("#level").show();
    } else {
        $("#level").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array of all the values you want, with the `includes()` method.

```
$("#department").change(function() {
    $("#level").toggle(["IT", "Engineering", "Product"].includes($(this).val()));
});
```

You can also use the `toggle()` function instead of `if/else` -- when the argument is a boolean, it hides or shows the element depending on the value.

Comment: Incredibly helpful! Thank you so much! I wonder if I can use something similar to "disable" certain checkboxes if "Checkbox A" has been selected.

Comment: Of course you can. `if ($("#checkbox-A").is(":checked")) { $(".certain-checkboxes").attr("disabled", true); } else { $(".certain-checkboxes").removeAttr("disabled"); }`